# Creating a CSV file from MySQL table using php

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

this code creates a csv file. However, I have avoided printing out commas in the fields because it is used as a delimeter (see line 22). Now I want to remove (carriage returns and new lines) from the fields. Adding  $somecontent .= str_replace("\n", "", $val); on line 23 does not seem to work. any ideas?

```
@chmod($export_csv, 0777);
    $fe = @fopen($export_csv."/export.csv", "w+");
    if($fe){           
        $somecontent = "";
        $fields_count = 0;
        // print field headers
        $db->query($sql_view);
        if($row = $db->fetchAssoc()){
            foreach($row as $key => $val){
                if($fields_count++ > 0) $somecontent .= ",";
                $somecontent .= ucfirst($key);
            }
        }
        $somecontent .= "\n"; 

        // print field values
        $db->query($sql_view);
        while($row = $db->fetchAssoc()){
            $fields_count = 0;
            foreach($row as $key => $val){
                if($fields_count++ > 0) $somecontent .= ",";
                $somecontent .= str_replace(",", "", $val);
                $somecontent .= str_replace("\n", "", $val);
            }
            $somecontent .= "\n";                    
        }

        // write some content to the opened file.
        if (fwrite($fe, $somecontent) == FALSE) echo 'file_writing_error'." (export.csv)"; 
        fclose($fe);
    }
```

Comment: Why not try using PHP's built-in fputcsv() function?

Comment: thanks Mark: reading about it now. can you give me a head start to it, concerning what i have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your `$somecontent .= str_replace("\n", "", $val)`? I can't find it in your code.

You can specify an array as first parameter for `str_replace` as indicated [there](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Thus, it would replace each string present in your array with the second parameter.

For example, `$somecontent .= str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), "", $val);`

Comment: You're welcome ;) Even if it isn't the best solution, though it is for php4

Comment: @Geoffroy: there is a comma at each record end. any ideas?

Comment: @karto No, comma separates two values, and record are separated using either \n or \r or even \n\r. I mean if there is a comma at the record's end, you're expected to give on more value, even if it would also work

Comment: @Geoffroy:  price, address, description -->12,South Bay,good,

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't understand what you meant. Just add a verification: if it isn't the last value, don't add the comma at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Use [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function to write the CSV files. PHP already have a function to write csv files.

You do not need to handle escaping, delimiter by yourself all these already handled.

This will handle all these things for you and will save you from many headaches.

Comment: Thanks. has php 4 got this? I'll try it out. but the solution from Geoffroy worked for me.

Comment: @karto php 4 doesn't have this function, but it is better to use it. Try to upgrade your webserver

Answer (score 1):

You can do that [from MySql directly](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?79,11324,13062#msg-13062):

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/export.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM test_table;
```

Comment: thanks Gordon: I've tried your solution. it worked. But the solution from Geoffroy suites what i wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this, playing with ASCII caracters

```
$somecontent .= str_replace(CHR(10), " ", $val);
$somecontent .= str_replace(CHR(13), " ", $val);
```