# Exporting MYSQL data into Excel/CSV via php

Tags: php, mysql, database, excel

i want to Export MYSQL data into Excel/CSV via php. so that i can use my database later or someone can use and understand it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating a csv file from mysl table using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562925/creating-a-csv-file-from-mysl-table-using-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

You can create your own file by checking this address: http://www.programmingfacts.com/export-mysql-data-into-excelcsv-via-php/

I can't add working code in here sth is wrong =/

but make all \\t to \t and all \\n to \n

Answer (score 17):

To create a .CSV file with syntax suitable for EXCEL you can use basic SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
INTO OUTFILE '/mytable.csv'
FIELDS ESCAPED BY '""'
TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

See the manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html).

Comment: How can I also export the header of table in csv?

Answer (score 9):

I have searched so much for this on google, but the only code that is simple and IS WORKING is the one below. Create a downloadxls.php file (or name it whatever.php), copy/paste the code below, complete the host, username, password, database and table sections at the beginning of the code, and there you have a very nice working code. Then load the php file in your browser, and the xls file will be downloaded. I've tried it, and I'm using it.

All the best :)

```
    <?php
// Author: Linmic, email: linmicya@gmail.com

$host = ""; // your db host (ip/dn)
$user = ""; // your db's privileged user account
$password = ""; // and it's password
$db_name = ""; // db name
$tbl_name = ""; // table name of the selected db

$link = mysql_connect ($host, $user, $password) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die('Could not select database');

$select = "SELECT * FROM `".$tbl_name."`";

mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8;');
$export = mysql_query($select); 
//$fields = mysql_num_rows($export); // thanks to Eric
$fields = mysql_num_fields($export); // by KAOSFORGE
$col_title="";
$data="";
for ($i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++) {
    $col_title .= '<Cell ss:StyleID="2"><Data ss:Type="String">'.mysql_field_name($export, $i).'</Data></Cell>';
}

$col_title = '<Row>'.$col_title.'</Row>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($export)) {
    $line = '';
    foreach($row as $value) {
        if ((!isset($value)) OR ($value == "")) {
            $value = '<Cell ss:StyleID="1"><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>\t';
        } else {
            $value = str_replace('"', '', $value);
            $value = '<Cell ss:StyleID="1"><Data ss:Type="String">' . $value . '</Data></Cell>\t';
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim("<Row>".$line."</Row>")."\n";
}

$data = str_replace("\r","",$data);

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$xls_header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<Author></Author>
<LastAuthor></LastAuthor>
<Company></Company>
</DocumentProperties>
<Styles>
<Style ss:ID="1">
<Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left"/>
</Style>
<Style ss:ID="2">
<Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left"/>
<Font ss:Bold="1"/>
</Style>

</Styles>
<Worksheet ss:Name="Export">
<Table>';

$xls_footer = '</Table>
<WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
<Selected/>
<FreezePanes/>
<FrozenNoSplit/>
<SplitHorizontal>1</SplitHorizontal>
<TopRowBottomPane>1</TopRowBottomPane>
</WorksheetOptions>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>';

print $xls_header.$col_title.$data.$xls_footer;
exit;

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add Export button:

```
<button  type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onClick="tableToExcel('testTable', 'W3C Example Table')"   title="Export to Excel">Export</button></div><br/>
```

Add id to table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover " border="1" id="testTable" >
```

Add script at below of body:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var tableToExcel = (function() {
              var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
              , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
              , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
              , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
              return function(table, name) {
                if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
                  var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
                window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
              }
            })()</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use PHP, consider the [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function. But you can export from MySQL to text format without PHP. See [this page](http://christianriesen.com/2009/06/creating-a-mysql-dump-in-csv-format/) on using mysqldump.

Answer (score 1):

Try the fputcsv function. Also the MySql CE (5.2) Workbench is a good tool for both exporting the data and getting a picture of the database as a diagram.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//EDIT YOUR MySQL Connection Info:
$DB_Server = "localhost";        //your MySQL Server
$DB_Username = "root";                 //your MySQL User Name
$DB_Password = "";                //your MySQL Password
$DB_DBName = "school";                //your MySQL Database Name
$DB_TBLName = "s_question";                //your MySQL Table Name

if(isset($_POST['exp_stdque'])) {
    $exstdid = $_POST['expstd'];

//$DB_TBLName,  $DB_DBName, may also be commented out & passed to the browser
//as parameters in a query string, so that this code may be easily reused for
//any MySQL table or any MySQL database on your server

//DEFINE SQL QUERY:
//edit this to suit your needs
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName WHERE std_id = $exstdid";

//Optional: print out title to top of Excel or Word file with Timestamp
//for when file was generated:
//set $Use_Titel = 1 to generate title, 0 not to use title
$Use_Title = 1;
//define date for title: EDIT this to create the time-format you need
$now_date = DATE('m-d-Y H:i');
//define title for .doc or .xls file: EDIT this if you want
$title = "Dump For Table $DB_TBLName from Database $DB_DBName on $now_date";
/*

Leave the connection info below as it is:
just edit the above.

(Editing of code past this point recommended only for advanced users.)
*/
//create MySQL connection
$Connect = @MYSQL_CONNECT($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password)
     or DIE("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR() . "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());
//select database
$Db = @MYSQL_SELECT_DB($DB_DBName, $Connect)
     or DIE("Couldn't select database:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR(). "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());
//execute query
$result = @MYSQL_QUERY($sql,$Connect)
     or DIE("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR(). "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());

//if this parameter is included ($w=1), file returned will be in word format ('.doc')
//if parameter is not included, file returned will be in excel format ('.xls')
IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1))
{
     $file_type = "msword";
     $file_ending = "doc";
}ELSE {
     $file_type = "vnd.ms-excel";
     $file_ending = "xls";
}
//header info for browser: determines file type ('.doc' or '.xls')
HEADER("Content-Type: application/$file_type");
HEADER("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=database_dump.$file_ending");
HEADER("Pragma: no-cache");
HEADER("Expires: 0");

/*    Start of Formatting for Word or Excel    */

IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1)) //check for $w again
{
     /*    FORMATTING FOR WORD DOCUMENTS ('.doc')   */
     //create title with timestamp:
     IF ($Use_Title == 1)
     {
         ECHO("$title\n\n");
     }
     //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
     $sep = "\n"; //new line character

     WHILE($row = MYSQL_FETCH_ROW($result))
     {
         //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
         $schema_insert = "";
         FOR($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
         {
         //define field names
         $field_name = MYSQL_FIELD_NAME($result,$j);
         //will show name of fields
         $schema_insert .= "$field_name:\t";
             IF(!ISSET($row[$j])) {
                 $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
                 }
             ELSEIF ($row[$j] != "") {
                 $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
                 }
             ELSE {
                 $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
                 }
         }
         $schema_insert = STR_REPLACE($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
         $schema_insert .= "\t";
         PRINT(TRIM($schema_insert));
         //end of each mysql row
         //creates line to separate data from each MySQL table row
         PRINT "\n----------------------------------------------------\n";
     }
}ELSE{
     /*    FORMATTING FOR EXCEL DOCUMENTS ('.xls')   */
     //create title with timestamp:
     IF ($Use_Title == 1)
     {
         ECHO("$title\n");
     }
     //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
     $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

     //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
     FOR ($i = 0; $i < MYSQL_NUM_FIELDS($result); $i++)
     {
         ECHO MYSQL_FIELD_NAME($result,$i) . "\t";
     }
     PRINT("\n");
     //end of printing column names

     //start while loop to get data
     WHILE($row = MYSQL_FETCH_ROW($result))
     {
         //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
         $schema_insert = "";
         FOR($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
         {
             IF(!ISSET($row[$j]))
                 $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
             ELSEIF ($row[$j] != "")
                 $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
             ELSE
                 $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
         }
         $schema_insert = STR_REPLACE($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
         //following fix suggested by Josue (thanks, Josue!)
         //this corrects output in excel when table fields contain \n or \r
         //these two characters are now replaced with a space
         $schema_insert = PREG_REPLACE("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
         $schema_insert .= "\t";
         PRINT(TRIM($schema_insert));
         PRINT "\n";
     }
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All thanks to Linmic and @Kaszoni Ferencz for sharing this. Nothing more then updated to PDO as mysql functions no more available.

```
// Author: Linmic, email: linmicya@gmail.com
// Updated By: Najm
$host = ""; // your db host (ip/dn)
$user = ""; // your db's privileged user account
$password = ""; // and it's password
$db_name = ""; // db name
$table_name = "";// table name of the selected db
$skip_column=[];// skip any column not needed in excel    
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8","$user","$password",[PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true]);

$export = $db->query("DESCRIBE $table_name"); 
$fields = $export->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
$columns = "";
foreach($fields as $v)
{
    if(in_array($v,$skip_column)) continue;
    $columns .= ",".$v;
}

$columns = substr($columns,1);
$select = "SELECT $columns FROM `$table_name`";

$col_title="";
$data="";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($fields); $i++) {
    if(in_array($fields[$i],$skip_column)) continue;
    $col_title .= '<Cell ss:StyleID="2"><Data ss:Type="String">'.$fields[$i].'</Data></Cell>';
}
$col_title = '<Row>'.$col_title.'</Row>';
$export = $db->query($select);

while($row = $export->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    $line = '';
    foreach($row as $value) {
        if ((!isset($value)) OR ($value == "")) {
            $value = '<Cell ss:StyleID="1"><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>\t';
        } else {
            $value = str_replace('"', '', $value);
            $value = '<Cell ss:StyleID="1"><Data ss:Type="String">' . $value . '</Data></Cell>\t';
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim("<Row>".$line."</Row>")."\n";
}
//echo "<textarea cols=50 rows=50>".$data."</textarea>";

$data = str_replace("\r","",$data);

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$xls_header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<Author></Author>
<LastAuthor></LastAuthor>
<Company></Company>
</DocumentProperties>
<Styles>
<Style ss:ID="1">
<Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left"/>
</Style>
<Style ss:ID="2">
<Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left"/>
<Font ss:Bold="1"/>
</Style>

</Styles>
<Worksheet ss:Name="Export">
<Table>';

$xls_footer = '</Table>
<WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
<Selected/>
<FreezePanes/>
<FrozenNoSplit/>
<SplitHorizontal>1</SplitHorizontal>
<TopRowBottomPane>1</TopRowBottomPane>
</WorksheetOptions>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>';

print $xls_header.$col_title.$data.$xls_footer;
exit;
```