# How to export MySQL data into a CSV file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I came across this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38328008/15691137

The script works to some extent, I was able to export the data into a xls file. But, the code has links to a deprecated html version. Also, the exported xls file gives an error when I try to open it which is as follows:
[image]

How can I update the code to use html5 instead of 4?. Also, how can I fix the error that I am facing? Can someone please help me with this code. Thank you.

Add Export button:

```
<button  type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onClick="tableToExcel('testTable', 'W3C Example Table')"   title="Export to Excel">Export</button></div><br/>
```

Add id to table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover " border="1" id="testTable" >
```

Add script at below of body:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var tableToExcel = (function() {
              var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
              , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
              , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
              , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
              return function(table, name) {
                if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
                  var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
                window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
              }
            })()</script>
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, but a CSV file is simply formatted as "column,column,column".

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error, right click the file -> Properties (or select the file and hit Alt+Enter), then check the box named 'Unblock'. That message actually isn't an error. It just warns you that the file may be corrupted.

Comment: not helpful at all. Am I supposed to add this message for the users who are going to download the file?

Comment: I need permanent solution, thank you for your time.